# GraphQl subscription throwing exception when subscribing with Apollo server flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-graphql

GraphQl subscription throwing exception **"web socket connect failed"** when subscribing with Apollo server. Subscription is working fine with graphQl explorer but failing when implemented in flutter

Code and exceptions are attached below.

********** Code ***********

```
final _wsLink = WebSocketLink(    
  ‘***************’,    
  config: SocketClientConfig(
    autoReconnect: true,
    inactivityTimeout: Duration(hours: 1),
    // delayBetweenReconnectionAttempts: Duration(seconds: 1),
  ),  
); 

final Link _link = Link.split((request) => request.isSubscription, _wsLink, httpLink);
     
client = GraphQLClient(     
  cache: GraphQLCache(store: InMemoryStore()),
  link: _link,  
);

SubscriptionOptions options = SubscriptionOptions(
  document: gql(query),
  variables: variables);

final result = client.subscribe(options);

result.listen((event) {
  print("Event fired ${event.data}");
  print("Event fired ${event.exception?.graphqlErrors.toString()}");
}).onError((e) {
  print("Received Error ! ${e.toString()}");
});

return result;
```

************ Exception ***************

**I/flutter ( 5204): Disconnected from websocket.**

Answer (score 0):

I'm late but this works for me, if you have Apollo Server 4

```dart
final HttpLink httpLink = HttpLink(
    'http://192.168.43.29:4000/graphql', // my localhhost
  );
  
   final AuthLink authLink = AuthLink(
      getToken: () async => 'Bearer $token',
    );
    Link link = authLink.concat(httpLink);

    WebSocketLink websocketLink = WebSocketLink(
      'ws://192.168.43.29:4000/graphql/subscriptions', // my localhhost
      config: SocketClientConfig(
          autoReconnect: true,
          inactivityTimeout: const Duration(seconds: 30),
          initialPayload: {
            'token': token,
          },
          ),
      subProtocol: GraphQLProtocol.graphqlTransportWs, // This line is important, by default protocol is GraphQLProtocol.graphqlWs
    );

    if (websocketLink != null) {
      link =
          Link.split((request) => request.isSubscription, websocketLink, link);
    }

    graphqlClient = ValueNotifier(
      GraphQLClient(
        link: link,
        cache: GraphQLCache(store: HiveStore()),
      ),
    );
```